# What is ⌊x.999...⌋?

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

> What is the Greatest Integer(Floor) Function of $x.\bar{9}$?

$x.\bar{9} = x + 1 \implies \lfloor x.\bar{9} \rfloor = x + 1$

But by observation, $\lfloor x.\bar{9} \rfloor = x$

So, which one is correct?

Comment: Do you mean the floor function?  If $x$ is an integer, $[x.999 \dots] = [x+0.999 \dots] = [x+1] = x+1$.  I'm not sure what you mean by "by observation," but it's not correct that $[x.999 \dots]  =x$.

Comment: If you are taking [ ] to mean the floor function, consider using \lfloor and \rfloor instead. [ ] is commonly taken to just mean the same as ( ) and is confusing on first sight.

Comment: @b00nheT Oh thanks!

Comment: I suspect that "by observation" means "we have $\lfloor x.99...9\rfloor=x$ for every finite block of nines, so surely $\lfloor x.\overline{9}\rfloor=x$ as well." But that's not an applicable argument: it tacitly assumes that the floor function is **continuous**, which of course it isn't. The whole point is that we see "jumps" when we hit an integer.